# How to handle Apple subscription with serverside verification

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am trying to implement a subscription in my flutter application, with server side verification. My code is pretty much a copy of the example of `in_app_purchase` package

```
Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdated(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    for (final PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        showPendingUI();
      } else {
        if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
          handleError(purchaseDetails.error!);
        } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
            purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
          final bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          if (valid) {
            unawaited(deliverProduct(purchaseDetails));
          } else {
            _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
            return;
          }
        }
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          if (!_kAutoConsume && purchaseDetails.productID == _kConsumableId) {
            final InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition androidAddition =
                _inAppPurchase.getPlatformAddition<
                    InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
            await androidAddition.consumePurchase(purchaseDetails);
          }
        }
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My `_verifyPurchase` method calls backend to verify the authenticity of the purchase, and returns a validity status.

The problem with Apple implementation is that, it streams all the purchases to this method. That means that all the old purchases are going through this method. If a user is subscribed for two years, every time they open the application, this method is invoked 24 times. That is not ideal and causes problems.

I tried filtering expired transactions, but I couldn't decode the verification data on the mobile, so I cannot access expiration date.

How can I tell a new purchase, from an already verified one?

Comment: What is the code at the native level doing?  Is it presenting the entire purchase receipt each time your app is opened? Why would it do that?

Comment: By the way, Apple's server side validation is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts)

Comment: Yes it is sending all the receipts for some reason. And I am not using the the old verify endpoint

Comment: When you get the receipt, it contains all previous transactions. You can examine the receipt in your app code and only send the most recent transaction, or you can not check the receipt at all and just process renewal transactions when they occur

Comment: Please try the purchases_flutter package (https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter) and go with RevenueCat it will save you a lot of headaches

Answer (score 0):

By using the purchases_flutter package you can first fetch your products, show them to the users (if not yet subscribed) and than offer a buy button for each product.

Fetch products, you will geht a List of StoreProduct

```
  final List<StoreProduct> products = await Purchases.getProducts([
    inAppProductPremiumMonthly,
    inAppProductPremiumYearly,
  ]);
```

Show the StoreProduct list to users and create a buy option, something like this:

```
Future<void> _buyProduct(StoreProduct product) async {
try {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => const LoadingWidget(),
  );
  await Purchases.purchaseStoreProduct(product);
  widget.callback(product);
} catch (e) {
  widget.errorCallback(e);
} finally {
  if (context.mounted) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}}
```